# Real Time Flask

Tags: python, flask

I am reading the data from a txt document. There is a lot of data from the TXT document. I want to parse this data. I want to send it to html in real time after splitting it into arrays. In addition, when I upload new data to the txt file while the website is online, I want it to upload this data to the arrays. The code I write is constantly showing repetitive data. Where am I making a mistake?

```
@app.route('/deneme6')
def deneme6():
    def generate():
        enlem=[]
        boylam=[]
        with open("20210318_irkit_test_1.txt") as file:
            csv_reader = csv.DictReader(file)

            for i in csv_reader:
                enlem.append(i['LATITUDE'])
                boylam.append(i['LONGITUDE'])
            data=[enlem,boylam]
        while True:   
            for item in data:                                                                                                                                                                          
                yield str(item)  
                    #yield data.read()
                sleep(1)
    return app.response_class(generate(), mimetype='text/plain')
```

Comment: Okay, what I don't understand is why you open the text file every time you get a request. If I were you, I'd load the text onto memory during initialization and not read that data over and over again. Am I missing something in your question ?

Comment: your data has two elements, your while is running those two elements non-stop

Comment: You're right about that. So where am I going wrong with this code? I want it to be updated as data is added to the txt. @rkrishnasanka

Answer (score 0):

I think this is an architecture problem rather than a code problem:

1. If your .csv file is constantly changing, I would not use REST and use WebSockets ([socket.io)](https://flask-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) instead (change it from a polling system to an async notification system)
2. If you need to monitor a CSV for changes (out of your control), I'd just have a [file monitor class](https://pypi.org/project/watchdog/) looking for changes on the file, look for the change, and then push the new data through the websocket connection.

My assumptions:

1. The client and server need to communicate changes in real-time.
2. You must absolutely get the data from a CSV file.

If assumption 2 is not true then I would recommend you use some kind of an in-memory database (could just be a static variable).